# Saving changes to EF with children

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have build reporting system where user can select data and display as report. Report is saved in three tables (split entity). But when I try to edit report and save again I get following error:

> An entity object cannot be referenced by multiple instances of IEntityChangeTracker

My Entity:

```
public class Report
{
    [Key]
    public int ReportId { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public int? DateRange { get; set; }
    public int Layout { get; set; }
    public DateTime? DateFrom { get; set; }
    public DateTime? DateTo { get; set; }
    public int OwnerId { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateCreated { get; set; }
    public bool Active { get; set; } 
    public virtual List<ReportCharts> ReportCharts { get; set; }
    public virtual List<ReportElements> ReportElements { get; set; }
}
```

My EF repository:

```
//Save Report to Database 
    public void Save(Report report)
    {
        assignSettingsToEntity(report);
        assignElementsToEntity(report);
        assignChartsToEntity(report);

        int found = Reports
            .Select(r => r.ReportId)
            .Where(id => id == report.ReportId)
            .SingleOrDefault();

        if (found == 0)
        {
            context.Reports.Add(report);
        }
        else
        {
            context.Entry(report).State = EntityState.Modified; // Here I get error 
        }
        context.SaveChanges();     
    }
```

My DBContext

```
class EFDbContext : DbContext
{
    //Get Lines data from Lines table
    public DbSet<Line> Lines { get; set; }

    //Get Shifts data from Shifts table
    public DbSet<Shift> Shifts { get; set; }

    //Get list of Charts from Charts table
    public DbSet<Graph> Graphs { get; set; }

    //Get Reports data from Reports table
    public DbSet<Report> Reports { get; set; }

    // Report entity mapping
    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Report>().Property(t => t.ReportId).HasColumnName("ReportId");
        modelBuilder.Entity<Report>().Property(t => t.Title).HasColumnName("Title");
        modelBuilder.Entity<Report>().Property(t => t.DateRange).HasColumnName("DateRange");
        modelBuilder.Entity<Report>().Property(t => t.Layout).HasColumnName("Layout");
        modelBuilder.Entity<Report>().Property(t => t.DateFrom).HasColumnName("DateFrom");
        modelBuilder.Entity<Report>().Property(t => t.DateTo).HasColumnName("DateTo");
        modelBuilder.Entity<Report>().Property(t => t.OwnerId).HasColumnName("OwnerId");
        modelBuilder.Entity<Report>().Property(t => t.DateCreated).HasColumnName("DateCreated");
        modelBuilder.Entity<Report>().Property(t => t.Active).HasColumnName("Active");
        modelBuilder.Entity<Report>().HasMany(t => t.ReportElements).WithRequired().HasForeignKey(c => c.ReportId).WillCascadeOnDelete(true);
        modelBuilder.Entity<Report>().HasMany(t => t.ReportCharts).WithRequired().HasForeignKey(p => p.ReportId).WillCascadeOnDelete(true);
        modelBuilder.Entity<ReportElements>().Property(c => c.ElementName).HasColumnName("ElementName");
        modelBuilder.Entity<ReportElements>().HasKey(c => new { c.ReportId, c.ElementName, c.Active });
        modelBuilder.Entity<ReportCharts>().Property(p => p.ChartId).HasColumnName("ChartId");
        modelBuilder.Entity<ReportCharts>().HasKey(c => new { c.ReportId, c.ChartId, c.Active });
    }

}
```

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1):

Entity Framework attaches every entity to one context and all changes can only be performed on the context it is attached to it, you are probably using multiple context. You should detach and attach entity obtained from different context.

Otherwise, the best practice is not to use multiple instances of context, only keep one context throughout your changes.

Comment: I only use one context but few dbsets in the context, is that what you mean? I have edited my question to add DbContext class.

Comment: Where is save method? and what does add methods do? are you creating new context, by context I mean instance of context, you may have one class, but if you have multiple instances, that is problem.

Comment: Resolved: I have made mistake as I was loading entity to edit and assigning it to session variable which I believe now was the multiple instance which you mentioned. Many thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like the object was attached to another context and not detached.

```
   //Save Report to Database 
    public void Save(Report report)
    {
      using(EFDbContext context=new EFDbContext ())
      {
        assignSettingsToEntity(report);
        assignElementsToEntity(report);
        assignChartsToEntity(report);

        int found = context.Reports
            .Select(r => r.ReportId)
            .Where(id => id == report.ReportId)
            .SingleOrDefault();
        // Insert Flow
        if (found == 0)
        {
            context.Reports.Add(report);
        }
        // Update flow
        else
        {
            context.Reports.Attach(report);
            context.Entry(report).State = EntityState.Modified; 
        }
        context.SaveChanges(); 
      }         
    }
```